# How to display a cube data in charts in C# winform use MDX?

Tags: c#, winforms, cube, adomd.net

I want to create a a chart to demonstrate data from `mdx query`.

I am using `Adomd.net`. I have cube with  3 dimensions `Date`, `Customer`, `Internet Sales Fact`.

I'm using `AventureWorkDW2012`. I want to demonstrate sale amount in every quarter in a year so my code is below

```
string query=@"SELECT [Measures].[Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS,[Order Date].[Hierarchy].[Calendar Year].&[2013].Children ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works DW2012]"  
 AdomdCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            AdomdDataAdapter ad = new AdomdDataAdapter(query, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ad.Fill(dt);
            chart1.DataSource = dt;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "[Measures].[Sales Amount]";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "[Order Date].[Hierarchy].[Calendar Year].&[2013].Children";
```

That code gives error

> Column with name '[Order Date].[Hierarchy].[Calendar Year].&[2013].Children' was not found.

I just found out the error is caused because the `chart` just read data from `COLUMNS` and my quarter is on `ROWS`.

My question is how can I print out the values on  `ROWS`?

Comment: So, what do the column names in the DataTable look like??

Comment: @TaW i edited my question with result query in datagridview

Comment: Well, I meant what are the Column Names in the DataTable?? The error after all complains about a name in your binding call that is not in the columns of the datatable.

Comment: @TaW oh thank i found the problem , you are right , i choose wrong name for the column

Answer (score 1):

i found the problem.the chart actually still reading data in rows but display it in column. I chose the wrong name to display that why it can't read  yvaluemembers.